# Ionic not working request with multiple images but this only happens on some devices

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working on a submit request, but the request wasn't sent. In the form the user is required to fill in 3 images, when clicking the save button it appears loading for a few seconds then disappears. When I checked back and forth it was not detected. However, this incident only occurred on a few devices out of 10k installers, the others had no problem. This is my code

```
save() {
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('homemeet_id', this.id);
  formData.append('name', this.credentials.controls['name'].value);
  formData.append('description', this.credentials.controls['description'].value);

  for(let i = 0; i < this.photos.length; i++){
    if(this.photos[i] != NOPHOTO_BASE64){
      formData.append('filename[]', this.b64toBlob(this.photos[i]));
    }
  }

  this.loading.presentLoading().then(() => {
    this.homeMeetingService.storeParticipant(formData).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.presentToastService.presentToast('Successfull created', 'success');
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(
          '/main/home-meeting-detail/' + this.id, { animationDirection: 'forward' }
        );

        this.loading.dissmissLoading();
      },
      (error) => {
        this.loading.dissmissLoading();
      }
    );
  }, (error) => {
    this.presentToastService.presentToast('Something went wrong', 'danger');
  });
}
```

Here is the code snippet for the base64 converter

```
b64toBlob(dataURI) {  
  var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
}
```

The problematic device really can't make requests for this form, but everything else works.

- Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
- Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.7.5
- @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.2.12
- @angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.2.7
- @angular/cli                  : 14.2.7
- @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0
- Capacitor CLI   : 5.4.0
- @capacitor/core : 5.4.0

Comment: With this info, it does not help. You need to get those devices and test yourself. Theres not much we can do.